# Twitter Log In Button using Fabric SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I want to log in my app using Twitter logIn Button, for that i'm using fabric SDK, when i select Xcode IDE in Fabric Page, I am getting error -

I have already given Organization name in setting Page.

[image]

Could any one tell me how could i use twitter native Log In button in my App ?

Answer (score 3):

I recently installed Fabric SDK. Did you provide your organization's email ID during the registration? If you did, you shouldn't be facing any issues. One suggestion I can provide is to try inviting a colleague of yours and see if it works.

Adding a login button in your app is very simple. In `AppDelegate.m`, import the header files

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
```

Then in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Fabric with:@[TwitterKit]];
    return YES;
```

}

Open your Main.Storyboard file. Add a UIButton. Select it and open the Identity Inspector (alt+cmd+3). In the Class textfield, enter "TWTRLogInButton". Open your `<Whatever>ViewController.m` and create a property

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet TWTRLogInButton *twLoginView;
```

In the `viewDidLoad` method, add the following line.

```
_twLoginView = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    // do whatever you wish to do with Twitter session instance.
}];
```

Comment: thanks for ur response. i will check it. is it possible to fetch user email address in twiter using fabric. Thanks

Comment: @Imran yes you can use `TWTRShareEmailViewController` to requester user email.

Comment: @thandasoru ... thanks bro. does it possible to get friends details like name, id etc using fabric. please update me

Comment: @thandasoru  i could not see where it s asking email and how can i share with freinds.. plz suggest me link

Comment: @Imran I haven't had the time to completely check out the Fabric SDK as I was completely busy with office work. There should be enough documentation in the twitter developer website.